# get delimiter index and convert EPOCH time

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I need to search time in the first line and get the position index and then convert other lines' EPOCH time to human readable time. The EPOCH time position is random but it has a header. Sample as below.

```
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,1667271686096
CDF,Palo Alto,1667271685202
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input is CSV, using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to convert the value in the `time` field (wherever it may occur in the order of fields) from Unix time to the current locale's representation of local time:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$time = strftime_local($time,"%+")' file
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,Sat Sep 27 01:54:56 CEST 54803
CDF,Palo Alto,Sat Sep 27 01:40:02 CEST 54803
```

```bash
$ TZ=Canada/Central mlr --csv put '$time = strftime_local($time,"%+")' file
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,Fri Sep 26 18:54:56 CDT 54803
CDF,Palo Alto,Fri Sep 26 18:40:02 CDT 54803
```

For UTC time, use `strftime()` in place of `strftime_local()`:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$time = strftime($time,"%+")' file
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,Fri Sep 26 23:54:56 UTC 54803
CDF,Palo Alto,Fri Sep 26 23:40:02 UTC 54803
```

For other time formats, give the `strftime()` or `strftime_local()` function a more specific time formatting string (see the manual for `strftime` on your system):

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$time = strftime_local($time,"At the hour %H of day %j of the year %Y")' file
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,At the hour 01 of day 270 of the year 54803
CDF,Palo Alto,At the hour 01 of day 270 of the year 54803
```

Depending on your version of Miller, and on your system, you may want to always use a more specific time formatting string, or you may want to switch to the easier-to-use `sec2gmt()` or `sec2localtime()` functions:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$time = sec2gmt($time)' file
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,54803-09-26T23:54:56Z
CDF,Palo Alto,54803-09-26T23:40:02Z
```

```bash
$ TZ=Europe/Stockholm mlr --csv put '$time = sec2localtime($time)' file
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,54803-09-27 01:54:56
CDF,Palo Alto,54803-09-27 01:40:02
```

```bash
$ TZ=Canada/Central mlr --csv put '$time = sec2localtime($time)' file
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,54803-09-26 18:54:56
CDF,Palo Alto,54803-09-26 18:40:02
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl, using the [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/release/List-MoreUtils) module for the `first_index` function to find the index number of the first field containing  "time", and [Date::Format](https://metacpan.org/release/TimeDate) for the `time2str()` function:

```
$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=first_index -MDate::Format -F, -lne '
  if ($.==1) {
    $tfield = first_index { m/time/i }, @F ;
  } else {
    $F[$tfield] = time2str("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$F[$tfield])
  };
  print join(",",@F)' file.csv
Name,city,time
ABC,New York,54803-09-27 09:54:56
CDF,Palo Alto,54803-09-27 09:40:02
```

Note: perl's `Date::Format` module has no problems with timestamps greater than [03:14:07 Jan 19, 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), and neither does perl in general since [perl v5.12](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.1/perl5120delta#Y2038-compliance) (released in April 2010). Other languages may or may not work accurately, depending on whether the language and/or OS are still using 32-bit signed integers for time values (Linux switched to 64-bit time_t on all architectures, even 32-bit arches, with v5.6 in 2020).

Also note that neither of the modules used are included as standard with perl. You'll have to install them with [cpan](https://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN), or via your distro's package manager if they happen to be packaged for your distro (e.g. on Debian and derivatives, `sudo apt-get install libtimedate-perl liblist-moreutils-perl`)